# Discount entry field not displaying on membership signup

Tags: civimember, cividiscount

A discount entry field is not displayed on my membership signup form. I have created membership types and created a discount for one of the membership types. The discount is active.  The top of my signup form looks like this:
[image: Signup form]

My discount looks like this:

[image: Membership discount code]

I added the price field options in hopes that would make it work, but it didn't. Any ideas?

I have other discounts for events and they work fine. I am using civi 5.4.1.

Comment: Hi KZ,

One of our clients just reported the same issue - I'll get back to you once I've figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

For the particular client that reported this, it turns out that the issue was caused by a change made to a membership type after the price set was already associated with the contribution page, but the error was only presented if one clicked on the Save button of Memberships tab of the contribution page configuration.

To confirm whether this is the case to you - navigate to the Memberships tab of your contribution page and click the Save button to see if you are presented with the following error message:

> The membership price set associated with this online contribution allows a user to select BOTH an auto-renew AND a non-auto-renew membership. This requires submitting multiple processor transactions, and is not supported for one or more of the payment processors enabled under the Amounts tab.

Meaning - when using a price set, you can either offer auto-renew for all memberships on a given page, or none of them, but you can't offer a mix. On the other-hand, if you use the built-in membership fees section, you can select which membership types you wish to have the option (or be required) to auto-renew (so long as your [**payment processor**](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Payment+Processors%20) supports auto-renewal).

If you don't have a payment processor that is configured to allow for auto-renewal:

1. Navigate to Administer > CiviMember > Membership Types
2. Ensure that the Auto-renew Option for all membership types is to to "No auto-renew option"
3. Navigate back to the Memberships tab of the contribution page and click the Save button - the message should no longer appear
4. Click on the Contribution Links button at the top and select Test or Live - the discount box should now appear (assuming that the discount code is configured accordingly).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, Tamar!  This didn't exactly fix my problem, but I did notice something strange. When I select the Test button, the discount box appears on the form. When I access the page normally, the discount box does not appear. Any idea as to what would cause this?

Comment: Hi KZ, There still might be an issue with the price set configuration that is preventing the discount box from appearing on the live page - the same type of verification may not be in place on the test page. Do you get any kind of error message when you click on the Save button in the Memberships tab? And can you confirm whether all of your membership types either offer or do not offer auto-renewal and whether your payment processor supports auto-renewal?

Comment: I do not get an error when clicking on the save button. I turned off auto-renew for all membership types. How do I know if my payment processor supports auto-renew?

Comment: If you turned off auto-renew for all memebership types, then that would not be the issue, but you can check whether your payment processor supports auto-renew at this link: https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Payment+Processors%20 >>> that said, contribution pages can be a bit funny with updating - try editing the contribution page, then click the Save and Done button without making any further changes, then access the live contribution page (perhaps in an incognito window), to make sure that what you are seeing is the current version and not the cached version.

Comment: I made a change, and I am seeing the current version. Still no discount box.  Also, on the test page I have the option to use PayPal, but on the live page, I only have the option to use a credit card.  Everything else on the page is the same.